# Add an IF condition to an existing FOREACH loop

Tags: php, foreach

I am making changes to some existing PHP code (on a Wordpress site). I am not a PHP programmer, but am learning.

I want to change the following section of code:

```php
if ( $terms1 = get_terms( 'location', 'orderby=name' ) ) :
    echo '<select name="location"><option value="">Location</option>';
    foreach ( $terms1 as $term ) :
        echo '<option value="' . $term->slug . '"' . ( $location == $term->slug ? ' selected' : '' ) . '>' . $term->name . '</option>';
    endforeach;
    echo '</select>';
endif;
```

I want to add a conditional into the `foreach` loop, to test if the value of `$term->slug` does NOT equal `western-australia`. So, I want the `foreach` to run only on all other values (except `western-australia`).

I tried the following, and it had no impact on the page output;

```php
if ( $terms1 = get_terms( 'location', 'orderby=name' ) ) :
    echo '<select name="location"><option value="">Location</option>';
    foreach ( $terms1 as $term ) :
        if ( $term->slug != "western-australia" ) :
            echo '<option value="' . $term->slug . '"' . ( $location == $term->slug ? ' selected' : '' ) . '>' . $term->name . '</option>';
        endif;
    endforeach;
    echo '</select>';
endif;
```

I found many similar questions re adding an `if` into a `foreach` but no answers that gave me a clear sense of how to approach this in my particular situation.

What's the way to go about this?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your `if` condition's syntax or logic. It could be that the value isn't exactly `western-australia`. Add `var_dump($term->slug);` before the `if`, that will display the exact values of all the slugs so you can see where the mismatch is.

Comment: Solution looks correct. I recommend switching to the default control structure syntax rather than [the alternative one you are using](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for better readability. Maybe a cache on your WP site is keeping the page from being changed - add some debug output!

Comment: Okay. Thanks for these comments. After a few more refreshes it's working as I wanted. Which is great. I thought this development instance had no caching, but will check if that's truly the case.

Comment: Thanks @ArSeN. All the custom coding has been done that way. Not sure why. I'd never seen that method before, so it took me a while to get my head around what I was looking at. Too much work to change it all, unless there's an automated way to do it. So will leave as it.